# LinkedIn embeddable follow widget has stopped working

Tags: linkedin-api

Over the past month the Follow widget have stopped working in major browsers.

I'm able to replicate and I have another user able to replicate, however for some users it works fine.

I've setup a test here: https://gleam.io/stuart-test

Neither of these buttons are clickable for me when logged into LinkedIn: http://recordit.co/CoCVu7CWd1

When logged out I see the Login Prompt just fine: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/spa/p0om8fe5anuc97l/fpya5qs_.png

As soon as I login the buttons disappear: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/spa/p0om8fe5anuc97l/f4nlhcqp.png

Refreshing I can see them, but they won't click.

There's some console errors: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/spa/p0om8fe5anuc97l/-i9j44ww.png Browsers tested: Latest Chrome OSX and Latest Safari (no plugins enabled)

You can just replicate the issue here: 
https://developer.linkedin.com/plugins/follow-company

Type in Nike under Company/Page Name Click Follow Nothing happens on any browser for me, once logged in.

Anyone from LinkedIn able to fix it?  Anyone else able to suggest workarounds?

Answer (score -1):

This is part of the LinkedIn experience.

Inspired from:

- "You're holding it wrong" - [Read More](https://www.engadget.com/2010/06/24/apple-responds-over-iphone-4-reception-issues-youre-holding-th/)